# How to animate(X scrolling) text in TextBox in UWP/WinRT app?

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, windows-runtime, uwp

I am making application in UWP and have read-only **TextBox** with strict-size.
I want to make users to only see and copy text from that box.
Unfortunately sometimes text inside is too long and to show it I will need to make scrolling animation in X axis. 
I do not know how to make it.

---

I tried:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 
 but I end up with errors with ToolTips control so removed it but still do not know what to edit to enable animation when text is too long for TextBox.

---

Anybody know solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `height` to Auto, and `TextWrapping` to `Wrap`, then the textbox will take the available space as needed..

Better solution is to use a selectable TextBlock w/ ScrollViewer as:

```
<ScrollViewer>
     <TextBlock IsTextSelectionEnabled="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: A problem is Height is also restricted :(

Comment: That's OK, do the second option I recommended to you, it's way better.

Comment: I will try that than

Comment: It is not exactly what I wanted but it's working. Thanks

Comment: If it's working, could you please accept my answer 

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
 <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Margin="10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" FontFamily="Consolas" Background="White" AcceptsReturn="True" IsReadOnly="True" InputScope="Text" ManipulationMode="System" RequestedTheme="Dark" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```